# checking valid? for model using minitest for Rails 4.1.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, minitest

I am new to rails. I was trying to write unit test(mintest 5.5.1) for a model. the Database i am using is a SQL server (i use the gem activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (4.1.0)) . The tables are created fine.

**Migration Script for model**

```
class CreateRpReports < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   create_table :rp_reports do |t|
     t.string :name, :null => false
     t.string :description

     t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

**Model Class**

```
class RpReport < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :name, presence: true

 def errors
  {:name => ["can't be blank"]}
 end  
end
```

**Unit test for RpReport Model**

```
require 'test_helper'

describe RpReport do

def valid_params 
 { name: "John Doe", description: "John Report" }
end

####TEST 1###
it "is valid with valid params" do
 rpReport = RpReport.new valid_params    
 rpReport.must_be :valid? #must create with valid params
end

####TEST 2### 
it "is invalid without a name" do
  params = valid_params.clone
  params.delete :name
  rpReport = RpReport.new params

  rpReport.wont_be :valid? #must not be valid without name

  rpReport.errors[:name].must_be :present? #must have error for
  missing   name
 end
end
```

I am getting error when i run rake test

**Test Output**

```
RpReport
test_0001_is valid with valid params                            FAIL  (0.01s)
Minitest::Assertion:         Expected #<RpReport id: nil, name: "John Doe", description: "John Report", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> to be valid?.
    test/models/rp_report_test.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

test_0002_is invalid without a name                            ERROR (0.00s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `add' for {:name=>["can't be blank"]}:Hash
        test/models/rp_report_test.rb:31:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    test/models/rp_report_test.rb:31:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'


Finished in 0.04500s
2 tests, 1 assertions, 1 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Can anyone assist in pointing out what mistake i am doing while writing the test

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting the error, is that you're overriding `errors` on the ActiveRecord model. I'm not sure why you have this:

```
def errors
  {:name => ["can't be blank"]}
end
```

Where did you read to add this? Plus, the error you specified should be the one already specified when an attribute is not provided.

If you would like to adjust what the error message says, you can do so this way:

```
class RpReport < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: { message: "can't be blank" }
end
```

And lose the `errors` method you added, no matter what you do. More info on validations and error messages can be found [in the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the error is with these lines in the model:

```
def errors
  {:name => ["can't be blank"]}
end
```

That doesn't make sense. Try deleting it.